# Binding a BPF descriptor to an interface

Tags: c, openbsd, bpf

I'm trying to write a small C program on an OpenBSD vm I just installed, and cannot get my file descriptor (to `/dev/bpf`) to bind to my interface.

OpenBSD info:

```
openbsd:waffles uplime$ uname -a
OpenBSD openbsd.securitea.app 6.5 GENERIC#3 amd64
openbsd:waffles uplime$ ifconfig
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 32768
    index 4 priority 0 llprio 3
    groups: lo
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
em0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    lladdr 00:0c:29:34:99:7b
    index 1 priority 0 llprio 3
    groups: egress
    media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT full-duplex,master)
    status: active
    inet 10.10.73.199 netmask 0xfffffc00 broadcast 10.10.75.255
em1: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    lladdr 00:0c:29:34:99:85
    index 2 priority 0 llprio 3
    media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT full-duplex,master)
    status: active
    inet 172.16.221.129 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 172.16.221.255
enc0: flags=0<>
    index 3 priority 0 llprio 3
    groups: enc
    status: active
pflog0: flags=141<UP,RUNNING,PROMISC> mtu 33136
    index 5 priority 0 llprio 3
    groups: pflog
openbsd:waffles uplime$
```

However, when I try to bind my descriptor to `em0`, I get the following error:

```
openbsd:waffles uplime$ cc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g -O1 -o tmp/test tmp/test.c
openbsd:waffles uplime$ doas tmp/test
ioctl: em0: Device not configured
openbsd:waffles uplime$
```

I'm using the following testcase:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <net/bpf.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  int fd = open("/dev/bpf", O_RDONLY);
  int packet_max = 32768;

  if(fd < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "open: /dev/bpf: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return 1;
  }

  if(ioctl(fd, BIOCSBLEN, &packet_max) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ioctl: BIOCSBLEN: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return 1;
  }

  struct ifreq req;
  memset(&req, 0, sizeof(req));
  strcpy(req.ifr_name, "em0");

  if(ioctl(fd, BIOCSETIF, req) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ioctl: em0: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I know the interface is fine, because it is the only one connected to the internet, and I'm able to make inbound/outbound requests without issue. I can also run `tcpdump -i em0` without issue. Am I missing an ioctl call (or something similar) to make the interface usable?

Comment: Have no experience coding for BPF, but are you sure opening the bpf device file read-only would let you bind it to the NIC with that second ioctl?

Comment: the interface `em0` has a modifier that only allows the group: `egress`  The interface `em1` has no such restriction.  Suggest using `em1`